# Java Spring: OAuth authentication failed: Unknown Error

Tags: java, spring, oauth

I am trying to run an example OAuth client in spring. When i run the application i receive exception:
`org.springframework.security.oauth.consumer.OAuthRequestFailedException: OAuth authentication failed: Unknown Error`

There are no further details in the exception and i tried to debug the code to see where it fails but without luck.

How can i troubleshoot such issues?

Below is the authentication manager configuration in application context:

```xml
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="user" password="pass" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <oauth:consumer resource-details-service-ref="resourceDetails" oauth-failure-page="/error">
        <oauth:url pattern="/person/login" resources="resource"/>
    </oauth:consumer>

    <beans:bean id="consumerService" class="com.apple.ist.idms.service.impl.PersonServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="personURL" value="${person-details-url}"/>
        <beans:property name="consumerTemplate">
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth.consumer.client.OAuthRestTemplate">
                 <beans:constructor-arg ref="resource"/>
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="oauthInputs" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="location" value="classpath:apple-idms-oauth-config.properties"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <oauth:resource-details-service id="resourceDetails">
        <oauth:resource id="resource"
                        key="${consumer-key}"
                        secret="${consumer-secret}" request-token-url="${request-token-url}"
                        user-authorization-url="${user-authorization-url}"
                        access-token-url="${access-token-url}"
                        request-token-method="${request-token-method}"
                        access-token-method="${access-token-method}">
        </oauth:resource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check source [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/13b36fbb4163c6b5b603b642846745f5776f5a9a/spring-security-oauth/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth/consumer/client/CoreOAuthConsumerSupport.java#L215) and [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/13b36fbb4163c6b5b603b642846745f5776f5a9a/spring-security-oauth/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth/consumer/client/CoreOAuthConsumerSupport.java#L241). There are two places where this message is created.
It looks like you miss something in `oauth:resource`